# Plane embedded in Non-Euclidean spacetime

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, geometry

The AdS-Schwarzschild black hole metric is given by,

$$ds^2 = \frac{1}{z^2} \left( -f(z) dt^2 + \frac{dz^2}{f(z)} + dx^2 \right)$$

where $t$ is time, $z$ is the radial direction, $x$ is a transverse spatial direction, $f(z) = 1-m z^4$, and $m$ is a constant mass.

Now for my question, we can always transform the constant mass $m$ AdS-Schwarzschild spacetime into a time-dependent mass $m(u)$ spacetime which is given by the AdS-Vaidya black hole metric,

$$ds^2 = \frac{1}{z^2} \left( -f(u,z) du^2 - 2 du dz + dx^2 \right)$$

The transformation that allows this is given by,

$$u = t - \int \frac{dz}{f(u,z)}$$

where $u$ acts like the new time coordinate, $f(u,z) = 1 - m(u) z^4$ and $m(u) = 1000 e^{-3 u}$. The ranges are $t \in [\epsilon, 1]$, $u \in [\epsilon, 1]$, $z \in [\epsilon, 1]$, $x \in [\epsilon, 1]$, and $\epsilon = 10^{-2}$.

Clearly this spacetime is non-Euclidean so obviously this is a spacetime with warping effects. Now, is it possible to visualize a constant plane $u=x$ in this time-dependent spacetime *in the ($t,z,x$)* coordinates using some `Graphics` like `ParametricPlot3D` or `Plot3D`? In other words, given the values of $(u,z,x)$ I have the AdS-Vaidya spacetime, and we can visualize the constraint $u=x$ in this coordinate system. However, what I want is to visualize the AdS-Vaidya spacetime as well as the constraint $u=x$ in the $(t,z,x)$ coordinates.

The constraint $u=x$ is a flat plane with zero intrinsic curvature, but embedded in the $(t,z,x)$ coordinates it will definitely have some extrinsic curvature where the plane *bends* due to the warping effect of the given spacetime.

Comment: Is $u$ indeed defined as the quantity which satisfies that equation beginning with $u = \cdots$? It's just strange to me that $u$ appears on both sides of the equation, so I wanted to check before attempting an answer.

Comment: Also, in case I don't have time, just wanted to mention `ContourPlot3D`, which might be useful to you. :)

Comment: @thorimur Yes, originally the mass $m$ is time-independent. Now, mass depends on time which is played by $u$. Actually the transformation should be written as $t = u + \int dz/f(u,z)$ which looks less weird.

Comment: Ah, ok. And this is the integral from $\epsilon$ to $z$, or from $\epsilon$ to $\infty$ (or something else)?

Comment: @thorimur That is an indefinite integral, then after integration we can take the values of $z$ to be anywhere between $\epsilon$ to any positive value, but of course practically it shouldn't be too big, $z=1$ would be a practical max value. I think I should just change that in the post.

Comment: But indefinite integrals are only unique up to an additive constant—to have a real thing to compute with, we need to know the lower bound of integration (or, equivalently, for what $z$ we should have $u = t$)

Comment: @thorimur Oh, yeah... $u = t$ at $z = \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simple approach in case it helps (not a full answer), noting that we can phrase the constraint $u=x$ in terms of $t$ by substituting $x$ in for $u$ in $t = u + \int \frac{dz}{f(u,z)}$:

```
\[Epsilon] = 10^-2;

f[u_, z_] := 1 - (1000 E^(-3 u)) z^4

intIndefinite[u_, z_] := Evaluate@Integrate[1/f[u, z], z]

int[u_, zz_] := 
 Evaluate[intIndefinite[u, zz] - intIndefinite[u, \[Epsilon]]]

tPlane[x_, z_] := Evaluate[x + int[x, z]]

ContourPlot3D[t == tPlane[x, z],
  {t, \[Epsilon], 1}, {x, \[Epsilon], 1}, {z, \[Epsilon], 1},
  AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

However, the artifacts are pretty terrible in the result. This could be reduced by increasing `PlotPoints` above its default, but that takes very long. Also something looks off—I wonder if we're the victims of a branch cut somehow, as logs and arctans appear in `?intIndefinite`. Unfortunately (and strangely), `Integrate[1/f[u, zz], {zz, \[Epsilon], z}]` takes ages to finish, and I'm not sure it will. So, I wonder if it's worth working through the integral from $\epsilon$ to $z$ by hand, then using `Compile` on the result so that it's fast. But hopefully this partial answer helps get things started!

Comment: I edited the range of $z$ in the code to $[\epsilon, 0.5]$ to reduce the computation time and I used `PlotPoints->10` which I guess already shows a bit of the features of the plane. I believe whatever is shown by `ContourPlot3D` written in your code assuming we can neglect some artifacts should be correct right? The plot I got using your code is quite good with some artifacts on small portions only.

Comment: @mathemania Maybe, but maybe not because of branch cuts! I'd inspect the expression `int[u,z]` carefully, and maybe make sure that the plot `Plot3D[int[x, z], {x, \[Epsilon], 1}, {z, \[Epsilon], 1}, PlotRange -> Full]` makes sense. I notice that sometimes the output is invisible because it's nontrivially complex (check out `int[0.5,0.5]`), which seems like a red flag. In particular, this happens when we cross $f(u,z)=0$.